# Convert String in Hash SHA-256 format with NUL(e.g. "/000")

Tags: jmeter, rsa-sha256

Using JMETER, I would like to convert below String in SHA - 256 Hash key notation

624111NUL2021-10-06T11:35:39-04:00NULs3cr3tNUL,

The correct supposed to be

7c3f952cdd1d6bf56a2762c5bb94add00883654794d27344f1dd55e5901f381c

while using below hash function

${__digest(SHA-256,624111NUL2021-10-06T11:35:39-04:00NULs3cr3tNUL,,,)}

Unfortunately not getting the correct result from the above function, I came to know, NUL characters between the fields and at the end (3 total NUL characters).  These are hex 00 characters.  They show as NUL in Notepad++ but they are really hex 00.
e.g. Id+ "\000" + timestamp + "\000" + salt + "\000"

Any idea to manage the same in JMeter to get correct SHA 256 Key

Answer (score 0):

Just go for [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) which allows executing arbitrary [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) where you can have [Unicode escape sequences](https://javajee.com/unicode-escapes-in-java):

```
${__groovy(org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex('624111\0002021-10-06T11:35:39-04:00\000s3cr3t\000'),)}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dmitri :-), It's working..

Comment: Hi @@Dmitri, Hope you are doing well. Need your help again, if you are aware How to use BCrypt in place of SHA256 in groovy function what you shared few months back.